# How can I tell what version/s of gcc are currently installed on my Linux server?

Tags: linux, gcc

I am on a Linux server and I want to know what versions of `gcc` are available/installed. What commands can I run to check this?

Comment: Consult your package manager documentation on listing installed versions of packages.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of [Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516691/how-can-i-tell-what-version-s-of-gcc-are-currently-installed-on-my-linux-server#comment62537313_37516709) was most helpful.

```
ls /usr/bin/gcc*
```

gives a list of the form

```
/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc-6
/usr/bin/gcc-ar
/usr/bin/gcc-nm
...
```

and after ignoring all entries containg "-ar", "-nm", "-ranlib" and calling the remaining entries with the "-v" option one gets the concrete versions.

Example

```
/usr/bin/gcc-6 -v
```

The same holds for g++ wqith `ls /usr/bin/g++*`.

Answer (score 0):

To see what version is active use:

```
gcc -v
```

To see all installed versions use (Gentoo):

```
gcc-config -l
```

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure 'gcc-config -l' is the correct command?

Comment: It might be distro specific (I use gentoo)

Comment: All versions can usually be found with $ `ls /usr/bin/g++*` ( $ `ls /usr/bin/gcc*` ) ... Using, example : $ `export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && [other command]` ... where [other command] can be e.g. `./configure` -